# Checking if data already added and pending in session using SQLALchemy when batch committing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on seeding a database using a few web scrapers I've written. I'm trying to avoid committing after every iteration and commit in batches. I'm using the following code to check if data exists in table before adding.

```
class ModelMixin(Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.utcnow())

    @classmethod
    def get_or_create(cls, session, **kwargs):
        entry = session.query(cls).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
        if not entry:
            logger.info('Inserting')
            entry = cls(**kwargs)
            session.add(entry)
        return entry
```

Now I'm running into a problem where there is duplicated data within a batch. Since its within a batch, the data hasn't been committed, and passes the *if not exists in table* logic above. Then of course I get a unique violation when I go to commit since.

What I'd like is to check if exists in pre-commit batch.

```
if entry not in session.pending:
      session.add(entry)
```

**edit:**

Trying to implement session.get as per Gord Thompsons suggestion below but I must be missing something

```
>>> data = {'id': 315253, 'html': '<h1>lorem ipsum</h1>'}
>>> session.add(DataLake(**data))
>>> 
>>> session.new
IdentitySet([DataLake, ID: 315253])
>>> 
>>> session.get(DataLake, 315253) # id just added returns none
>>> session.get(DataLake, 92742) # id in database returns instance
DataLake, ID: 92742
```

Comment: [Session.get()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get) looks in the session first, and if the item is not there then it queries the database. So if you can identify the "duplicate data" by primary key then you could use `.get()` to perform the check.

Comment: @GordThompson That looks promising thanks! I must be misunderstanding how session.get is implemented. Could you take a look at the edit in my original post?

Also, one of my tables has a unique constraint on a non-pk string field but I suppose I could just make it a pk.